# mysql insert query performance

Tags: java, mysql, performance

I am running ten different Java programs in order to insert some data to a MySQL database. All these programs run parallel and try to insert data to a table at the same time. I have 24GB of RAM and i7 CPU. It seems that I have enough resource to use. How can I increase the memory which MySQL uses and maybe some tips to increase the overall performance. Please note that finally I have to insert 300M records and I need to search them as fast as possible afterwards.

MySQL 5.6

Thanks

Update:

I have no index
I am using a simple windows pc with 24GB of RAM and i7 3.2 GHz cpu
I have installed wampserver (mysql 5.6 included)

my table is like this:
id    text   date number1 number2

My code is in java and simple connections to mysql and insert queries

I get the data from a webpage (simple html reading)

The main problem is number of records which is about 250M

Comment: Why don't you drop all of the Indexes before the insert, then add the indexes back?

Comment: Do you have indexes on that table?  If so, did you drop them?

Comment: No I have no index on the table

Comment: Please provide more information about your environment -- what kind of disks? What kind of data? What's your database schema look like? What's the code you're using to insert data look like? The devil is in the details, and you haven't given any.

Comment: I answered the questions you asked ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few of the things that you can consider:

- Drop all indexes
- disable Query cache
- make `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0` i.e. 0 means Write the log buffer to the log file and flush the log file every second, but do nothing at transaction commit.
- disable `sync_binlog`. The `sync_binlog` option controls how MySQL flushes the binary log to disk.
- most importantly insert by auto increment primary key not with UUID

Comment: disabling query cache is only useful for this case since I only use insert queries, yes?

Comment: @nimafl nope. you need all. `insert` is also belong to some transaction.